# AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'title' Web2py

Tags: web2py

Been a long day hoping to get a bit of help :)

I am developing a search form in web2py, I create the form like this

```
<table>    
<form method="post" action="{{=URL('views', 'search')}}">
    <tr><td><label>Enter Keywords</label></td><td><input style="background-color: lightgreen; color:#333; font-weight:bold; width:260px;" type="text" name="tags"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label>Select Region</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="region" style="width:260px">
    <option value="" style="background-color: darkgreen; color:#FEFEFE; font-weight:bold; width:260px;">Choose a Region...

    {{for region in region_query:}}
    <option value="{{=region.id}}" style="background-color: lightgreen; color:#333; font-weight:bold; width:260px;">{{=region.title}}</option>
    {{pass}}
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
        <label>Select Category</label>
            </td>
    <td>

    <select name="category" style="width:260px;">

    <option value="" style="background-color: darkgreen; color:#FEFEFE; font-weight:bold; width:260px;">Choose a Category
    {{for cat in cat_query:}}
    <optgroup label="{{=cat.title}}" style="background-color: darkgreen; color:#FEFEFE; font-weight:bold; width:260px;">
    {{sub_query = db(db.sub_category.main_category == cat.id).select(orderby=db.sub_category.title)}}
    </optgroup>
    {{for sub in sub_query:}}
    <option value="{{=sub.id}}" style="background-color: lightgreen; color:#333; width:260px;">{{=sub.title}}</option>

    {{pass}}
    {{pass}}
    </select>



    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right">
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: lightgreen; color:#333; font-weight:bold; width:260px; height:30px" value="Search Business Directory">
    </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

My controller consists of this

```
def search():
    mystr = str(request.post_vars["tags"])
    if mystr == "" or mystr == None:
        return redirect(URL('default', 'error_search'))
    region = str(request.post_vars["region"])
    if region == "" or region == None:
        return redirect(URL('default', 'error_search'))
    category = str(request.post_vars["category"])
    if category == "" or mystr == None:
        return redirect(URL('default', 'error_search'))
    featured = db((db.featured_listing.tag_words.like('%'+mystr+'%')) | (db.listing.region.contains(region)) | (db.listing.sub_category.contains(category))).select(orderby=db.featured_listing.title)
    query = (db.listing.tag_words.like('%'+mystr+'%')) | (db.listing.region.contains(region)) | (db.listing.sub_category.contains(category))
    orderby = db.listing.title
    pcache = (cache.ram, 15)
    paginate = Pagination(db, query, orderby, display_count=10, cache=pcache, r=request, res=response)
    search_query = paginate.get_set(set_links=True)
    return dict(search_query=search_query, featured=featured)
```

My view for the resultant search contains this

```
{{for query2 in featured:}}                                                                        

    <div class="listingItem">
    <div class="listingItem-content">
        <h2>{{=query2.title}}</h2>
    ....
```

etc etc

I receive this error when searching

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/var/www/web2py/applications/GreenPages_web/views/views/search.html", line 47, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Any idea how I can fix this and achieve the results I am looking for.

Thank your for any advice given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
featured = db((db.featured_listing.tag_words.like('%'+mystr+'%')) |
    (db.listing.region.contains(region)) |
    (db.listing.sub_category.contains(category))).select(orderby=db.featured_listing.title)
```

The above query references two different tables (`db.featured_listing` and `db.listing`). The result will therefore include fields from both tables, so you will need to reference fields in each record using both the table name and the field name. If the "title" field is in the `db.featured_listing` table, you would have to refer to it via `query2.featured_listing.title` rather than `query2.title`.

Note, although your query references two tables, it does not involve a join, so this query may not be returning what you expect.

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Inner-joins.